# Spotfire visualization - Over in a running total gets blank values?

Tags: visualization, data-visualization, spotfire

I have built a bar chart visualization with Spotfire that includes the use of the Over function to give a running total. Months are on the X axis and counts are on the Y axis. 
My data set contains months where there were no values. When I graph that there is no bar although a running total should still contain a value although zero was added for that month.

How do I get a month with no value to still show a bar for that month?

Comment: Do you have any information about Spotfire? Do you have any code to show?

Comment: Sorry that I forgot the code:  
Count() OVER (AllPrevious([Axis.X]))

Also can someone tag this thread with "Spotfire"?

Comment: You should add that to the original question and format it

Comment: Do any of the answers so far answer your questions? If no please add comments detailing why or add more info to your question, otherwise please consider marking one as answered as per http://stackoverflow.com/about

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can try Count() OVER (AllPrevious([Axis.X])), this will work for bar chart and line chart. or if you r using 55.0 and above version you can use Cummulative function which is inbulit is recent versions.
Hope this help :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my data set (note the 2 missing values):

```
Month   Value
Jan-14  1
Feb-14  2
Mar-14  
Apr-14  
May-14  5
Jun-14  6
Jul-14  7
Aug-14  8
Sep-14  9
Oct-14  10
Nov-14  11
Dec-14  12
```

Here is my expression (taken from the built in Cumulative function):

```
Sum([Value]) THEN Sum([Value]) OVER (AllPrevious([Axis.X]))
```

Here is my result:

[image: Spotfire graph]
So it looks like your expression is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

since I saw this old topic and didn´t find a solution at first, there it is:

the formula is good, but displaying the months with no values is an option of the bar chart itself.

Go to the bar chart "**Properties**", then "**Appearance**", then at the bottom of the window: tick the box "Compensate for missing values".

Hope this will prevent next users from searching in the future :)