# Using OVER function in Spotfire to produce cumulative sum in a data table

Tags: spotfire

I have a beginner question about OVER statements and cumulative summing:

Imagine that I have a table that has years in the first column, and sales in the second column, e.g.:

```
Year  Sales
2001  10
2002  20
2003  30
...
```

What I want to do is add the sales from one year to the next, and have these running down a column in Spotfire. With the case of the first year, I just want to show sales for that year, e.g.

```
Year  Sales Year sales + Year -1 sales
2001  10    10
2002  20    30
2003  30    50
...
```

I tried the following OVER statement:

```
If(
  Count([Year]) over (Previous([Year]))=0, 
  [Sales], 
  [Sales] + Sum([Sales]) Over (Previous([Year])))
```

... but I get the weird result of:

```
Year  Sales  Year sales + Year -1 sales
2001  10     10
2002  20     <seemingly null>
2003  30     50
...
```

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong? In short, I'm trying to work out how to have a different result against the first node (I think this is the correct term!! :) )

I played around using the `THEN` statement as described in this [SO page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19297965/spotfire-visualization-over-in-a-running-total-gets-blank-values), but did not seem to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This formula should help you get the desired result.

```
Sum([Sales]) over (LastPeriods(2,[Year]))
```

[image: YearSales]