# Spotfire: Sum() OVER (Previous()) blanking out second node when used with If() statement

Tags: spotfire

I have the situation where I have a table that looks like the following:

```
Year   Sales
2000   100
2001   225
2002   375
2003   490
...
```

What I want to do is:

- If it is the first value, put in a value of my choosing
- If it is not the first value, calculate the difference between the previous Sales value and this Sales value

Here's what I am trying to achieve:

```
Year   Sales   NewColumn
2000   100     50        <For now, use Sales * 0.5>
2001   225     125
2002   375     150
2003   490     115
...
```

Here's the custom expression I'm using in a custom column:

```
If(
  Sum([Net Sales]) over (Previous([Year])) is null,
  (Sum([Net Sales]) over ([Year])) * 0.5,
  ([Sales] - Sum([Sales]) over (Previous([Year]))) 
)
```

However, this is what my formula returns:

```
Year   Sales   NewColumn
2000   100     50      
2001   225     <seems to be blank>
2002   375     150
2003   490     115
...
```

Now, I'm confused at this point: the `Previous` statement will return null when looking at the first node. So if I ran `([Sales] - Sum([Sales]) over (Previous([Year])))` I would get:

```
Year   Sales
2000   
2001   225
2002   375
2003   490
...
```

... but when I couple this logic with an `if` statement, it seems like everything is "shifted" a row down. Any thoughts on what I'm (clearly) misinterpreting here? Why has the focus of `Previous` apparently moved one row down?

(For clarity, this extends on my previous SO post here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36750108/using-over-function-in-spotfire-to-produce-cumulative-sum-in-a-data-table))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with your if statement. It is excluding the row sets where Sum([Sales]) over (Previous([Year])) are null from calculations where Sum([Sales]) over (Previous([Year])) is not null.

I would use SN([Sales] - Sum([Sales]) over (Previous([Year])),Sum([Sales]) over ([Year]) * 0.5).

Comment: Ah brilliant -- I was completely unaware of the `SN()` function. But, for my own education, is it possible to accomplish the above result with an `If()` or `case()` statement?

Comment: What version of Spotfire are you using? Off hand; I can't think of a clean way of doing it in one column (which doesn't mean there isn't one), but with nested aggregations in version 7 onward it might be possible.

Comment: I'm on v7.0.1. What is the reason for this breaking `if()` statements, and having to use `SN()`? -- do null values "break" `if()`'s?

Comment: The if statement is breaking the data into 2 sets, then evaluating them separately. In your example, year 2001 becomes the first row in the 2nd set and therefore has no previous value.

 See the ‘More about using if in expressions’ section on this page…. It describes a pretty similar example in detail. http://spotfire-ondemand.tibco.com/SpotfireWeb/Help/GUID-4C346A1C-68C8-405A-B217-98F6C1027629.html.